# Moverio bt-300 with Unity 5.5.1 + Vuforia

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia, epson

I'm trying to run an Unity (5.5) app inside an Android project on Moverio bt 300. The Android app runs fine but when I try to start Unity scene, I get a black screen.

Any idea ? (I also installed the moverio bt 300 plugin from Unity Asset Store) **Might be due to Vuforia, looks like it's not compatible with bt 300 for now**

**EDIT: Vuforia + Unity works fine on BT 200, so it really looks like Vuforia is just not yet supported on Moverio BT 300**

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Vuforia has not ported the AR platform to the BT-300 or BT-350 yet. I have no idea when/if they will.